# Relationship between fatty acid chain and saponification number

Tags: biochemistry, fatty-acid-synthase

Why do long chain fatty acids have low saponification number? What is the relation of fatty acid chain( R)  with saponification number?

Answer (score 4):

The saponification number, or saponification value, can be described as...

> the measure of the amount of alkali required to saponify a definite weight of fat. It is expressed in milligrams of potassium hydroxide required to saponify 1g of fat.

[(source: Food Analysis: Theory and Practice. Y. Pomeranz and C. E. Meloan)](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=DUL7B7JegcUC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Notice that, in the definition, we're talking about *grams* and *milligrams*, not mols.

Now comes the important information: in the saponification, the base reacts with the ester group, and any triglyceride, regardless its chain length, has exactly three ester groups.

Let's see this is an oversimplified example:

Suppose we have two triglycerides, A and B. A has a chain twice as long as B. So, suppose that a given number of mols of A weights around two times the weight of the same number of mols of B.

However, they have *the same number of esters*, and they will require the same amount of potassium hydroxide. As A has a greater weight (which is in the denominator on our equation), it will have a lower saponification number compared to B.

Comment: You might add some citations too.

Comment: @another'Homosapien' I just did, but some times it's absolutely useless. Have a look at this answer: http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/48341/24284 I explained that flowers are modified leaves. I provided half-dozen books, and I quoted even "Nature"! But the first comment is from a person saying "It would be too far-fetched saying what you're saying"... and 2 downvotes. Apparently, "Nature" is not enough for this site.

Comment: Well I can't tell about that kind of "person"s but its like a rule to put citations, so I just reminded you about that :)